# Smarty template - trouble making checkbox values as selected for dynamic checkbox names

Tags: php, smarty

I have a several fields like for person's profile and for each field there are several options.

For e.g.

```
Age (10-15, 15-20, 20-25) 
Category (X, Y, Z)
```

and several other fields.

I have search page with all these fields along with their option values as check-boxes.
So I am currently printing these values using below for-each loop

```
{foreach from=$field.options item=options}
<input name="{$field.field_search_name}[]" type="checkbox" value="{$options.url}" />
{$options.caption}
{/foreach}
```

Now issue is in making all the fields which are selected before submit, I need to show as 
selected from POST array.

I know that if we had static check-box name like "category[]" I could have done like below

```
{if in_array($options.url, $smarty.post.category)} checked {/if}
```

but in my case the check-box name is also dynamic and it is defined in smarty template only so I am not sure how to get work around for this.
Something like below has to be worked on , please let me know if it is possible to do this in smarty.

```
{if in_array($options.url, $smarty.post.$field.field_search_name)} checked {/if}
```

Comment: I am looking for help in this issue. Let me know if any more details are required from my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have the check-boxes checked as per the POST fields set in the request you can access them through:

```
{if array_key_exists({$smarty.request, $field.field_search_name)}
    checked
{/if}
```

However that would depend on the input names being unique. If you're using field names with `[]` to make them be an array when the form is submitted, you should check on whether the value is in the array.

This requires a little hack to access the array:

```
{assign var=tempFieldName value=`$field.field_search_name`}

{if in_array({$smarty.request.$tempFieldName, $options.url)}
    checked
{/if}
```

To be honest though, I'd recommend generating a unique name for each input rather than putting several in the same name, and separating them using `fieldName[]` to push the values into the array anonymously. Doing that would reduce the issues you're seeing with not being able to access the POSTed variable directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it works as desired.

I was trying as below, where **$postArr** is assigned from PHP file **$_POST** is assigned, I should have tried more, but thanks for you help

     {assign var=fldname value=$field.field_search_name}
     {if array_key_exists($fldname, $postArr)}
     checked
     {else}
     <!--checked-->
     {/if}

Comment: Please don't forget to assign the 'bonus'.

Comment: This answer should be revised to fix the order of arguments in in_array(needle, haystack).